# Vaadin 23: How-to return Page with HTTP status 404 when route not found?

Tags: vaadin

I just downloaded sample project from  [start.vaadin.com](https://start.vaadin.com) and added RouteNotFoundView almost same as in [documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/routing/tutorial-routing-exception-handling).

```java
    public class RouteNotFoundView extends Div implements HasErrorParameter<NotFoundException> {
    @Override
    public int setErrorParameter(BeforeEnterEvent event, ErrorParameter<NotFoundException> parameter) {
        getElement().setText("Cannot not navigate to '"
                + event.getLocation().getPath()
                + "'");
        return HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND;
       }
    }
```

But it still return HTTP status 200

```
$ wget http://localhost:8080/notFound                                                                                                                        
--2022-04-05 14:13:51--  http://localhost:8080/notFound
Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 
Length: 3665 (3,6K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘notFound’

notFound                                        100%[====================================================================================================>]   3,58K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2022-04-05 14:13:51 (344 MB/s) - ‘notFound’ saved [3665/3665]
```

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, you should report it at https://github.com/vaadin/flow

Comment: @ollitietavainen reported https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/13421

Answer (score 0):

So I filled the [bug report](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/13421) in Flow's GitHub Repo.

Currently workaround is: running the application with

```
vaadin.useDeprecatedV14Bootstrapping=true
```

But Client-side views written in TypeScript are not supported.